# Setup Sender's Avatar in Thunderbird Email html?

Tags: html, email, thunderbird, avatar

I have searched everywhere possible, found numerous questions, mainly rather old ones, but none help to solve the issue of adding my Avatar (my image, picture) to all emails I send from Thunderbird. For example, all emails I send from Gmail have my picture near my name. I want to get the same in Thunderbird. I realize that there is not built-in function. How can I do that with HTML? Where should I add html code? I will be very grateful for your help! Thank you!